# Mysql Counting the consecutive rows that match

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to run a MySQL query but not quite sure how to do it. I want to count the number of consecutive rows that match. For example

```
A A A B B B B A A
```

I want the outcome to be 3

It is easy to count the total number of `A` but im not sure out to out the 3 most recent only.

Here is an example of how im listing all

```
SELECT email,subject FROM tablename where email='test@example.com' and subject='FAIL';
```

---

**Edit**: Here is some sample data that might help. For simplicity We will just have ID and Subject and order by `ID`

```
ID Subject
1 FAIL
2 FAIL
3 FAIL
4 PASS
5 PASS
6 FAIL
7 PASS
8 FAIL
9 FAIL
```

The result should be either 3 or 2 depending on how you order `ID`

Comment: So you want to find how many `A` rows are consecutive start from first table row?

Comment: Yes. The query is to find out the number or consecutive backup failures have happened in a row. This example showing that there have been 3 failures in a row.

Comment: Given that rows in a table have no 'order' (in the conventional sense) how do we know which one is first and which is second?

Comment: Good point. I can order this by date

Comment: you should show a better example of sample data, and what you would expect the output to be.

Comment: Added some sample data.

Comment: @dgibbs I know this is old but have you solved this? It seems that AgRizzo's solution works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I loaded a SQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5349a/1  However, in your sample data, you had two ID=5.  I made it unique.  Also my SQLFiddle data doesn't match yours anymore since I changed some values to make sure it worked.  Have fun with it :)  (This works looking at the largest ID value for the sequence)

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT Subject, MAX(ID) AS idlimit
  FROM t
  GROUP BY Subject
  ORDER BY MAX(ID) DESC
  LIMIT 1,1) as Temp
JOIN t
  ON Temp.idlimit < t.id
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks this this is what I am after. I will fully test and confirm solution later :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following way. All we need is to count of values changes e.g. where current value not equal the previous. in this example ID is a field for order it can be id,date,....

```
select count(*)+1
FROM T T1
where val<>(select val from T where T.id<T1.id order by id desc LIMIT 1)
```

`count(*)+1` because of the first sequence which has no previous value.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8565bb/6)

If you need to count only sequences with more than 1 values then you can use the following statement. Here `HAVING count(*)>1` means that we need only sequences from 2 or more values in row. If you need 3 or more then change it to `HAVING count(*)>2` and so on.

```
select 
  count(*) 
FROM 
  (
    select 
      Val, 
      Grp 
    from 
      (
        select 
          T1.id, 
          T1.val, 
          (
            select 
              max(id) 
            from 
              T 
            where 
              T.id < T1.id 
              and T.val <> T1.Val
          ) as Grp 
        FROM 
          T T1
      ) T1 
    group by 
      GRP 
    HAVING 
      count(*)> 1
  ) T3
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95f27/1)

Comment: I don't think that works - See this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/973a1/1:  I changed the table values, yet the answer stayed 3

Comment: @AgRizzo I've added one more query to find sequences with more then 1 value. Thanks

Comment: This is not correct. What you are actually counting is not the number of consecutive rows with the same value, but rather the number of discontinuities - i.e. how many times the value of a row is different from the value of the row before. 'ABABA' should produce an output of 1, but your script will output 5. A very clever solution... to a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a simple trick, if you find the first non-faildata id you can easily count the consecutive passes.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM 
 (SELECT ID FROM tablename 
 WHERE subject!='FAIL' LIMIT 1)
AS temp 
JOIN tablename ON temp.ID > tablename.ID
```