# SQL: Way to get highest count of consecutive rows with same value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the highest count of the number of rows with a consecutive value. For example, if below were a table and I counted the total number of consecutive 'A's I would get 5.

> 1. A
> 2. B
> 3. B
> 4. A
> 5. A
> 6. A
> 7. A
> 8. A
> 9. B

I am trying to find a neat way to do this in SQL. I am trying to do it with PHP but struggling, and have created a messy solution:

```
   $streaksql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable`";
   $streaksql = $modx->query($streaksql);

   $outcomecounter = 0;
   $highestoutcome = 0;

     while ($streak = $streaksql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                    $outcome = $row['outcome'];

                    if($outcome == 'A'){
                        $outcomecounter = $outcomecounter +1;

                        if($outcomecounter > $highestoutcome){
                            $highestoutcome = $outcomecounter;
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        $outcomecounter = 0;
                    }  
                };//WHILE

echo $highestoutcome;
```

I am  wondering if anyone know a neater way to do this in an SQL query?

Comment: You mean _consecutive_, right?

Comment: Oops yes I do - thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Counting the consecutive number rows that match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541762/mysql-counting-the-consecutive-number-rows-that-match)

Answer (score 2):

Try this logic,

```
select top 1 col1 from myTable
group by col1
order by count(col2) desc
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am having problems replicating it with my code. Any chance you could throw in an example?

Comment: Just of the sql query - I am having trouble understanding the purpose of col1 as I only need to work with the col with the values I want to count

Comment: Ans modified, please check, you can have only one col also in select.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select COUNT(*)+1
FROM your_table a1
where value=(select value from your_table where your_table.id<a1.id order by id desc LIMIT 1) AND value= 'A'
```

CMIIW :)

referrence from this post [Mysql Counting the consecutive number rows that match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541762/mysql-counting-the-consecutive-number-rows-that-match)

Answer (score 0):

Another Idea:

```
SELECT outcome, max(Amount) from (
    SELECT  outcome, 
    IF(@a =outcome, @b := @b+1, @b := 1) as "Amount",
    @a := outcome 
    FROM mytable
    WHERE false = (@b:=0)
    AND outcome = 'A'    
) as test
GROUP by outcome;
```