# Count consecutive rows with a particular status

Tags: mysql, count, rows

I need to count whether there are three consecutive failed login attempts of the user in last one hour.

For example

```
id    userid    status  logindate
1     1         0       2014-08-28 10:00:00
2     1         1       2014-08-28 10:10:35
3     1         0       2014-08-28 10:30:00 
4     1         0       2014-08-28 10:40:00
```

In the above example, status 0 means failed attempt and 1 means successful attempt.

I need a query that will count three consecutive records of a user with status 0 occurred in last one hour.

I tried below query

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total, Temp.status
FROM (
SELECT a.status, MAX( a.id ) AS idlimit
FROM loginAttempts a
GROUP BY a.status
ORDER BY MAX( a.id ) DESC
) AS Temp
JOIN loginAttempts t ON Temp.idlimit < t.id
HAVING total >1
```

Result:

```
total       status
2             1
```

I don't know why it display status as **1**. I also need to add a where condition on logindate and status field but don't know how would it work

Comment: What's your current query? Where does it fail?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541762/mysql-counting-the-consecutive-number-rows-that-match

Comment: @NoobEditor: the solution given at that post seems quite complex as i could not understand which field i need to fit in the query as per my table field. can you please guide more on this?

Comment: @neeraj : you gotta show anything you tried! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor: I have added my query in the question.

Comment: Would have been easy with the `LAG` function in SQL Server..  look for something similar in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For consecutive count you can use user defined variables to note the series values ,like in below query i have use `@g`  and `@r` variable, in inner query i am storing the current status value that could be 1/0 and in case expression i am comparing the value stored in `@g` with the status column if they both are equal like `@g` is holding previous row value and previous row's status is equal to the current row's status then do not change the value stored in `@r`,if these values don't match like `@g <> a.status` then increment `@r` with 1, one thing to note i am using order by with id column and assuming it is set to auto_increment so for consecutive 1s `@r` value will be same like `@r` was 3 for first status 1 and the again status is 1 so `@r` will 3 until the status changes to 0 same for status 0 vice versa

---

```
SELECT t.userid,t.consecutive,t.status,COUNT(1) consecutive_count
FROM (
SELECT a.* ,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = a.status THEN @r ELSE @r + 1 END consecutive,
@g:= a.status g
FROM attempts a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:=2, @r:=0) t1
WHERE a.`logindate` BETWEEN '2014-08-28 10:00:00' AND '2014-08-28 11:00:00'
ORDER BY id
) t
GROUP BY t.userid,t.consecutive,t.status
HAVING consecutive_count >= 3 AND  t.status = 0
```

---

Now in parent query i am grouping results by `userid` the resultant value of case expression i have name is it as `consecutive` and `status` to get the count for each user's consecutive status

---

> One thing to note for above query that its necessary to provide the
>   hour range like i have used between without this it will be more
>   difficult to find exactly  3 consecutive statuses with in an hour

### Sample data

```
INSERT INTO attempts
    (`id`, `userid`, `status`, `logindate`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0, '2014-08-28 10:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 1, '2014-08-28 10:10:35'),
    (3, 1, 0, '2014-08-28 10:30:00'),
    (4, 1, 0, '2014-08-28 10:40:00'),
    (5, 1, 0, '2014-08-28 10:50:00'),
    (6, 2, 0, '2014-08-28 10:00:00'),
    (7, 2, 0, '2014-08-28 10:10:35'),
    (8, 2, 0, '2014-08-28 10:30:00'),
    (9, 2, 1, '2014-08-28 10:40:00'),
    (10, 2, 1, '2014-08-28 10:50:00')
;
```

As you can see from id 3 to 5 you can see consecutive 0s for userid 1 and similarly id 6 to 8 userid 2 has consecutive 0s and they are in an hour range using above query you can have results as below

```
userid  consecutive  status  consecutive_count  
------  -----------  ------  -------------------
     1            2       0                    3
     2            2       0                    3
```

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/897e4/2)

Comment: Many thanks for providing the solution!! I was looking for exactly same query in which i could pass time range and number of attempts.

Answer (score 0):

M Khalid Junaid's answer is great, but his Fiddle Demo didn't work for me when I clicked it.

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87572/2/0) which works as of this writing.

In case it doesn't work later, I used the following in the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE attempts
    (`id` int, `userid` int, `status` int, `logindate` datetime);

INSERT INTO attempts
    (`id`, `userid`, `status`, `logindate`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0, '2014-08-28 10:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 1, '2014-08-28 10:10:35'),
    (3, 1, 0, '2014-08-28 10:30:00'),
    (4, 1, 0, '2014-08-28 10:40:00'),
    (5, 1, 0, '2014-08-28 10:50:00'),
    (6, 2, 0, '2014-08-28 10:00:00'),
    (7, 2, 0, '2014-08-28 10:10:35'),
    (8, 2, 0, '2014-08-28 10:30:00'),
    (9, 2, 1, '2014-08-28 10:40:00'),
    (10, 2, 1, '2014-08-28 10:50:00')
;
```

And this as the query:

```
SELECT t.userid,t.consecutive,t.status,COUNT(1) consecutive_count
FROM (
  SELECT a.* ,
    @r:= CASE WHEN @g = a.status THEN @r ELSE @r + 1 END consecutive,
    @g:= a.status g
  FROM attempts a
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:=2, @r:=0) t1
  WHERE a.`logindate` BETWEEN '2014-08-28 10:00:00' AND '2014-08-28 11:00:00'
  ORDER BY id
) t
GROUP BY t.userid,t.consecutive,t.status
HAVING consecutive_count >= 3 AND  t.status = 0;
```