# I need to find any 5 rows that match where clause and they occur "in a row" (they are neighbors)

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table for fictional fitness app.
Let's say that app is monitoring user progress on doing pushups day by day.

**TrainingDays**

```
id  | id_user  |  date  |  number_of_pushups
```

Now, I need to find if user have ever managed to do more than 100 pushups 5 days in a row.

I know this is probably doable by fetching all days and then making some php loops, but I wonder if there is possibility to do this in plain mysql...

Comment: maybe this could help :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541762/mysql-counting-the-consecutive-number-rows-that-match

Comment: @M.D, 100 in 5 days ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, the easiest way is to use variables.  The following gets all sequences of days with 100 or more pushups:

```
select grp, count(*) as numdaysinarow
from (select (date - interval rn day) as grp, td.*
      from (select td.*,
                   (@rn := if(@i = id_user, @rn + 1
                              if(@i := id_user, 1, 1)
                             ) as rn
            from trainingdays td cross join
                 (select @rn := 0, @i := NULL) vars
            where number_of_pushups >= 100
            order by id_user, date
           ) td
     ) td
group by grp;
```

This uses the observation that when you subtract a sequence of numbers from a series of dates that increment, then the resulting value is constant.

To determine if there are 5 or more days in a row, use `max()`:

```
select max(numdaysinarow)
from (select grp, count(*) as numdaysinarow
      from (select (date - interval rn day) as grp, td.*
            from (select td.*,
                         (@rn := if(@i = id_user, @rn + 1
                                    if(@i := id_user, 1, 1)
                                   ) as rn
                  from trainingdays td cross join
                       (select @rn := 0, @i := NULL) vars
                  where number_of_pushups >= 100
                  order by id_user, date
                 ) td
           ) td
      group by grp
     ) td;
```

Your app can then check the value against whatever minimum you like.

Note:  this assumes that there is only one record per day.  The above can easily be modified if you are looking for the *sum* of the number of pushups on each day.

Answer (score -1):

Order of records shouldn't be relied on, e.g. with ORDER BY you can change the sequence.

However, you have many functions at hand in a database, which also enables you to [use less PHP](http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/). What you want is [SUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function. Combined with a WHERE clause, this should get you started:

```
SELECT SUM(number_of_pushups) AS sum_pushups
FROM TrainingDays
WHERE date >= :start_day
AND user_id = :user_id
```

Comment: This only provides the total number of pushups, not the number of consecutive days where a limit of pushups has been exceeded.