# Group data and count based on consecutive occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql

***Tricky for me to define the problem, maybe you understand it through my dummy data***.

I have this data:

```
PK, TaskPK
1, 1    
2, 1     
3, 2    
4, 2    
5, 5    
6, 1 
7, 1     
8, 2 
9, 2   
10, 5    
11, 5
```

Now I have to count TaskPK so, I make this query

```
Select PK, TaskPK, Count(*)
From tbl
Group by TaskPK
```

Iit brought this result

```
TaskPK, Count(*)
1, 4
2, 4
5, 3
```

**But I want slight different result**
Like this

```
TaskPK, Count(*)
1, 2
2, 2
5, 1
1, 2
2, 2
5, 2
```

The above result based on **consecutive data occurrence**, as TaskPK start with 1 (it group together), then it change it 2 (it group together), then 5 (it group together) taskPK. ***But as TaskPK again shift to  1, then it should group seperatly not link with previous occurrence of 1, this task seperately count***, is this possible?

Comment: Mysql or Sql Server ?

Comment: I am working on mysql but it is pure based on sql, not mysql or sql-server. I just added these two tags so that question get more attention.  is this bad?

Comment: I'm preparing query. In the mean time have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541762/mysql-counting-the-consecutive-number-rows-that-match this thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Counting the consecutive number rows that match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541762/mysql-counting-the-consecutive-number-rows-that-match)

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan - Of course bad!! there are solutions which will work in Sql Server and not in Mysql and vice versa.. So tell one

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan - Example here is one way to do it using `Window` functions `LAG` and `SUM()OVER()` http://rextester.com/ORHUN52577 but this will not work in `Mysql`

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan - It is not going to be easy doing it in `Mysql`

Comment: @Prdp what about the above given links? i am checking that links

Comment: It's easy enough, but how will you know which one's which?

Comment: @Strawberry sorry what you said? mean

Comment: Does the order of the rows in the result matter?

Comment: @Strawberry off course, i have made ORDER BY PK DESC for this reason. will use this.

Comment: I don't follow ?!?

Comment: @Strawberry now you should follow man. it is mandatory

Comment: Order by pk desc would be 5,5,2,2,1,1

Answer (score 0):

For Mysql - User variables to keep track of contiguous segments.Then group by this contiguous segments which are kept track by an incrementing counter,

```
SELECT MAX(TaskPK),COUNT(*)
FROM(SELECT PK,TaskPK,CASE WHEN  TaskPK=@TaskPK THEN @rn ELSE @rn:=@rn+1 END as g,
@TaskPK := TaskPK as task
FROM Test,(SELECT @rn:=0,@TaskPK:='')x
ORDER BY pk)z
GROUP BY g
ORDER BY pk;
```

[See it working](http://rextester.com/WZVIP63880)

Comment: Hello, I tried running the code but got this error: `Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'z.PK' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`